# Opencv3 and Python 2.7 on Virtual Environment - AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'createLBPHFaceRecognizer'

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, virtualenv, face-recognition

I have a python function with opencv 3. it works without virtual environment.Also I installed opencv on venv from:[pyimagesearch](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/22/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-ubuntu/). i am trying to run that python function on venv, then it gives an error :

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'createLBPHFaceRecognizer'
```

without venv in terminal:

```
gkhan@Gkan ~/Masaüstü/face_recognizer $ python face_recognizer.py
Yol :./sinif/114.jpg.
114 Yuz Tanindi 12
```

with venv in terminal:

```
gkhan@Gkan ~/Masaüstü/face_recognizer $ workon cv
(cv)gkhan@Gkan ~/Masaüstü/face_recognizer $ python face_recognizer.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "face_recognizer.py", line 15, in <module>
    recognizer = cv2.createLBPHFaceRecognizer()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'createLBPHFaceRecognizer'
```

my python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import cv2, os
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# For Test
if 0==0:

    cascadePath = "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"
    faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascadePath)

    recognizer = cv2.createLBPHFaceRecognizer()
...
```

I am running Opencv3 with python 2.7 on Linux Mint 64 Bit

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From OpenCV 3, you have to get and build the [opencv_contrib](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib) repo. Then you can use the submodule "face".

Help on module cv2.face in cv2:

```
NAME
    cv2.face

FILE
    (built-in)

FUNCTIONS
    createEigenFaceRecognizer(...)
        createEigenFaceRecognizer([, num_components[, threshold]]) -> retval

    createFisherFaceRecognizer(...)
        createFisherFaceRecognizer([, num_components[, threshold]]) -> retval

    createLBPHFaceRecognizer(...)
        createLBPHFaceRecognizer([, radius[, neighbors[, grid_x[, grid_y[, threshold]]]]]) -> retval
```

Voila~ You can now use `cv2.face.createLBPHFaceRecognizer()`

Comment: Thank you so much, i didn't see face submodule. so it is working now.

Comment: How do I build it for Windows??

Comment: OpenCV's official website has a very clear introduction on installation. [Click here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html)

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way for me was to use anaconda package:

```
conda install -c menpo opencv3=3.1.0
```

Once installed, use `cv2.face.createLBPHFaceRecognizer()` or other face recognizers. Hope this helps

Comment: How to install conda?

Answer (score 4):

## try this

run this command to install the contrib

> python -m pip install opencv-contrib-python

after this is done 
use this attribute

```
recoginizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
```

Answer (score 2):

for python versions as 3.6 uses:

```
rec = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create();
```

Comment: you mean OpenCV version 3.0 and above.

Answer (score 0):

For windows users using python 3, you can get the opencv_contrib from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv%22here%22). My system is 64 bit so *opencv_python‑3.3.0+contrib‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl* is what I used. If you are 32 bit then choose the 32 bit version.

Open command prompt and navigate to the download folder and use the command

```
pip install opencv_python-3.3.0+contrib-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

Note: Use a command similar to the file you just downloaded and make sure to uninstall an older version before installing the new one with the contrib.
 I had to run:

```
pip uninstall opencv_python-3.3.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

before making the new installation.

Then make sure it's successful

```
>>>import cv2
>>>cv2.face
<module 'cv2.face'>
```

Instead of createLBPHFaceRecognizer(), you must use LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()

Answer (score 0):

For Python version 3.6.x, do this:

Open your terminal and install opencv-contrib-python

```
python -m pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

when you done with it use this

```
recoginizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
```

For More option you can do it like this way:

```
print(help(cv2.face))
```