# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'createLBPHFaceRecognizer'

Tags: python, macos, opencv

From [this question in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33620527/opencv3-and-python-2-7-on-virtual-enviorement-attributeerror-module-object) I understand the error should be solved by having opencv contrib, but the thing is that when I first built opencv using cmake using [this guide by pyimagesearch](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/15/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-osx/) , I had also built opencvcontrib. If I must rebuild it, how exactly should I do it?

This is the error:

> import cv2
>   cv2.createLBPHFaceRecognizer()
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "stdin", line 1, in module
>   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'createLBPHFaceRecognizer'

Also:

> import cv2
>   help(cv2.face.createLBPHFaceRecognizer)
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "stdin", line 1, in module
>   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'face'

Mac OS, Python 2.7, Opencv 3.2

Answer (score 1):

After searching high and low, I found that using `cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()` just do the trick for opencv 3.3.0 with opencv contrib. Hope you find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

createLBPHFaceRecognizer() is in the sub-module cv2.face in python. To access it you should use `cv2.face.createLBPHFaceRecognizer().`

Answer (score 0):

I have executed this command: pip install opencv-contrib-python 
it has install opencv **version** : 3.4.0,

and it works with this formula:

```
import cv2
recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
```