# setting up createLBPHFaceRecognizer

Tags: python, opencv

```
import cv2

recognizer = cv2.createLBPHFaceRecognizer()   

 AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'createLBPHFaceRecognizer'
```

can you guys please help me solve this error?

I tried `pip install opencv-contrib-python` , but still the same error.

I am using Python 2.7 and opencv3.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'createLBPHFaceRecognizer'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43294668/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-createlbphfacerecognizer)