# using OpenCV 2.4.1 & python 2.7.15 in windows 10 Attribute error: 'moduleobject has no attribute 'createLBPHFaceRecognizer'

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

```
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

recognizer=cv2.createLBPHFaceRecognizer();
path='dataSet'

def getImagesWithID(path):
    imagePaths=[os.path.join(path,f) for f in os.listdir(path)]
    faces=[]
    IDs=[]
    for imagePath in imagePaths:
        faceImg=Image.open(imagePath).convert('L');
        faceNp=np.array(faceImg,'uint8')
        ID=int(os.path.split(imagePath)[-1].split('.')[1])
        faces.append(faceNp)
        print ID
        IDs.append(ID)
        cv2.imshow("training",faceNp)
        cv2.waitKey(10)
    return np.array(IDs), faces
Ids,faces=getImagesWithID(path)
recognizer.train(faces,Ids)
recognizer.save('recognizer/trainingData.yml')
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "C:\Users\Documents\basic\engine\trainer.py", line 6, in
>   
>       recognizer=cv2.createLBPHFaceRecognizer(); AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'createLBPHFaceRecognizer'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Opencv3 and Python 2.7 on Virtual Environment - AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'createLBPHFaceRecognizer'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33620527/opencv3-and-python-2-7-on-virtual-environment-attributeerror-module-object)

Answer (score 1):

As said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33730528/5330223), you have to get and build the [opencv_contrib](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib) repo. Then you can use the submodule "face".

Or install it using `pip`,

```
$ pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

Then you can use as `recognizer=cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()` as looks like they have changed the name of the method. If you are still having problems you can further investigate it using

```
import cv2
print (help(cv2.face))
```

Which reveals all the methods available. I have found the changed name this way.

Comment: i am using open cv2 so, all the code is according to 2.1.43 documentation. please comment if you need to see my github code

Comment: I was wrong. There is a weird thing that the method name is changed. I edited the answer. Hopefully it resolves your issue